Autodesk APS - BIM360DM_ERROR when retrieving hubs using 3-legged auth
For a customer of mine I am setting up an integration to retrieve all documents from their BIM360 and Construction Cload projects and syncing them to the projects in their own (custom) software. To achieve this, I am using the Data Management API.
However, when retrieving the hubs the user has access to, no data is returned but three warnings are given. The ErrorCode returned  is BIM360DM_ERROR with a status code of 403. The warning is given three times; one for each BIM360 region.
I am using a three-legged auth token and calling this route:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/
To be sure this is not related to the scopes used to retrieve the auth token, I am currently authorizing all scopes found here:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/scopes/
Other BIM360 and Construction Cloud API calls work as intended using the same auth token and the same project IDs.
I am using Laravel 10 running on php8.2 and calling the Data Management API as follows:
 $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => "Bearer {$accessToken}",
        ])->get('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs');

The following response is returned:
{
   "jsonapi":{
      "version":"1.0"
   },
   "links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"https:\/\/developer.api.autodesk.com\/project\/v1\/hubs"
      }
   },
   "data":[
      
   ],
   "meta":{
      "warnings":[
         {
            "Id":null,
            "HttpStatusCode":"403",
            "ErrorCode":"BIM360DM_ERROR",
            "Title":"Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM US.",
            "Detail":"You don't have permission to access this API",
            "AboutLink":null,
            "Source":null,
            "meta":null
         },
         {
            "Id":null,
            "HttpStatusCode":"403",
            "ErrorCode":"BIM360DM_ERROR",
            "Title":"Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM EMEA.",
            "Detail":"You don't have permission to access this API",
            "AboutLink":null,
            "Source":null,
            "meta":null
         },
         {
            "Id":null,
            "HttpStatusCode":"403",
            "ErrorCode":"BIM360DM_ERROR",
            "Title":"Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM APAC.",
            "Detail":"You don't have permission to access this API",
            "AboutLink":null,
            "Source":null,
            "meta":null
         }
      ]
   }
}

Does anybody know where I am making an error / which permission is not correctly set? Thank you in advance for any help!
